# I need help getting json data to my vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I have the following code, using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
 Dim address2 As String = 
 "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/" 
                                  & FlatLabel7.Text & "/entry?api_key=API KEY"
 Dim client2 As WebClient = New WebClient()
 Dim reader2 As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client2.OpenRead(address2))
 Dim json2 As JObject = JObject.Parse(reader2.ReadToEnd)
 FlatTextBox2.Text = json2.SelectToken(FlatLabel7.Text).SelectToken("tier")
```

but it doesnt find the "tier".

The json goes like this:

```
    {"28170580": [{  
   "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",  
   "name": "Name"  
   "entries": [{  
      "leaguePoints": 54,  
      "isFreshBlood": false,  
      "isHotStreak": false,  
      "division": "I",  
      "isInactive": false,  
      "isVeteran": false,  
      "losses": 32,  
      "playerOrTeamName": "asdfasda",  
      "playerOrTeamId": "ffdsfsaf",  
      "wins": 34  
   }],  
   "tier": "SILVER"  
}]}
```

I think its because it must go to a [0] before entering the "tier", but i dont know how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thats not a valid json string or you only copied part of it

Comment: You might as well use the [WebClient.DownloadString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to keep it simple. Don't forget to `.Dispose()` it when you're done with the WebClient.

Comment: this json is not valid, there must be a comma between "Name" and "entries".

Comment: Thank you. I've found a solution :D

Comment: But now i have another problem...

Now i need to, if the WebException is "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." (error 404) it does something...

how can i do it?

I have: If FlatLabel4.Text = "Nível: 30" Then
heres the part that then if there is a 404 then, do this, if it doesnt get any error, do that. Thanks again